# Select a folder directory in react without scanning the selected folders

Tags: html, reactjs

In react, I want to let user select a folder in the directory tree of operation system. The only info I need is the the folder path (no files info inside the folder are needed).

I have tried the below code

```
<input
 type="file"
 webkitdirectory="true"
 onChange={event => this.props.onSelect(event)}
 style={Style.folderSelectionInput}
/>
```

It returns extra `event.target.files` infomration. If the folder I selected contains lots of files, the `onChange` takes quite long time to be invoked. Is there a way to only return the selected folder path so the onChange can be called immediately even on a large folder?

Comment: Have you found a solution by any chance? I'm having the same issue

Comment: Hey, Please let us know if you have come across a solution to achieve this.